# Android New Updated Market App Menu Icons

Tags: android, icons

Has anyone seen a icon library that has the thin style gray scale look as the new updated android market app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, install the new SDK APIs and look into these platforms within the SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

Really don't know what you exactly mean. maybe you post some screenshot or give more details.

1. [here is a list of some quite good icon-packs](http://androgeek.com/android-icon-packs-basics-and-a-list-of-free-icon-sets.html)
2. [if you are searching for psd-templates to get your own icons](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)
3. [vector graphics to use for icons](http://www.enfew.com/11-best-icon-packs-for-mobile-app-developers/)